# How can I film my two hands?

Tags: dslr, iphone, technical

In filming a video diary, I am often trying fruitlessly to put my two hands in the frame (as I stand, walk, etc) to show in the video when I am doing certain things with my hands.

It is difficult to achieve, as I have tried with iPhone and with DSLR/mirrorless cameras as well as with camcorders, and holding the device, as well as seeing the screen to frame and focussing were all very difficult.

Has anyone achieved this? I would love an answer that explains solutions on how to do this with an iPhone as well as with a DSLR/mirrorless camera. A tripod cannot be an answer, unless if it fits on my head or shoulders.

Comment: Technically (although this would be a very heavy and bulky solution) you could use a tripod: if you make all the legs as short as possible and then strap them around your head, you could make a first-person view—but what a drag lol

Answer (score 1):

Go Pro offers both headbands and helmet mounts for their cameras.  Once you learn how to position and aim your head-mounted camera based on what you want it to see, you then only need a mechanism to start/stop the camera.  WiFi support and an appropriate app can be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. However, I am still wondering if this can be done with iPhone or SLR

Answer (score 0):

you could build an overhead rig and use an external monitor to view what is being see on the screen, there are many videos on sites like YouTube to see how these are built and work

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really need to see the video as you're shooting it, you could simply strap your phone to your chin (if you need it to move like your field of vision) or you could also strap it in the space where the neck and chest meet, with a slight tilt (if all you need to film is your hands). This is a very DIY solution and can be adjusted as you please if you have legos or spare plastic or cardboard lying around.

If you don't mind buying something, there are straps specifically designed for first-person video. Check out [https://www.amazon.com/Head-Mounted-First-Person-Shooting-Compatible-Smartphones/dp/B08L6MTKMQ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08L6MTKMQ) or other similar products.